# Toggle visibility javascript for div ID works in Chrome, not Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, toggle

Please can someone help me, I have some DIVs on an html page that I set to not show when the page is opened, but when the user clicks the links on the page, I want the content of the DIV to show. The visible content switches depending on the link clicked. The issue is that it works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Can someone help me to do the right code so that it works in both browsers?

Here is the code I have that turns off the DIVs:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function change_visibility(div_id)
{
document.all['itinerary'].style.display = (div_id == 'itinerary') ? 'block' : 'none';
document.all['touroptionals'].style.display = (div_id == 'touroptionals') ? 'block': 'none';
document.all['map'].style.display = (div_id == 'map') ? 'block': 'none';
document.all['dates'].style.display = (div_id == 'dates') ? 'block': 'none';
document.all['hotels'].style.display = (div_id == 'hotels') ? 'block': 'none';
document.all['includes'].style.display = (div_id == 'includes') ? 'block': 'none';
document.all['tourdates'].style.display = (div_id == 'tourdates') ? 'block': 'none';
document.all['price'].style.display = (div_id == 'price') ? 'block': 'none';
}

//-->
</script>
```

Inside the page I have these links:

```
<div id="tourmenu" >  
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="change_visibility('itinerary');">Full Itinerary</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="change_visibility('touroptionals');">Optional Extras</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="change_visibility('map');">Map</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="change_visibility('hotels');">Hotels</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="change_visibility('includes');">Includes &amp; Excludes</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="change_visibility('dates');">Dates</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="change_visibility('price');">Price</a>
</div>
```

In Chrome this all works perfectly, the DIVs do not show, and when I click each link, only that DIV with its content shows. In Firefox they all show all the time, and clicking the links does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `document.all`? That won't work in Firefox, and it hasn't been good JS style in a decade. Where did you get this code from?

Answer (score 1):

`document.all` is not supported by all browsers. Please use `document.getElementById` to be safe.

Comment: Finally got it working using the following in the function:

    document.getElementById('itinerary').style.display = (div_id == 'itinerary') ? 'block' : 'none';

old code was:
 
    document.all['itinerary'].style.display = (div_id == 'itinerary') ? 'block' : 'none';

The original code is what I found using Google because I could not find an example of how it should look. Now it works in both Chrome and Firefox. Its frustrating getting a reply but not a proper example of how things should look so I thought I would post the solution for other people like me who are crap at coding.